# How to load different picklist values other than present in application

Tags: data-loader, picklist

How can I load different picklist values for a field,values which are not present in application.I have a picklist field is having few values in application,but i have to load values that is different to these values.

Comment: I have used data-loader,but got the error.For that picklist field 'Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set.' is checked.Could this be the problem.

Comment: For example: A picklist field 'Pick',it is having a,b,c values.But I want to load value 'd' through data loader.

Comment: Try going to the specific field in your organisation and removing the option to restrict the picklist values. That should fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load different values, you'll need to ensure the settings on that field allow it.

i.e. turn `Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set.` off.

If you're using global picklists, this may not be an option.